# Jump to play audio

Tags: javascript

I have created a playlist using jPlayer and jQuery cookie plugins. I set a cookie session to save currentTime and playing track number.

How can I start the audio from last saved currentTime and track number when the browser reloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. After setting the item to play, you can set the time:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', playnow);
```

Take a look at [your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/ssvs23u7/1/).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play), it looks like the play method takes a number as the second parameter to tell it the time to start playing from, otherwise it will start from the beginning.

```
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play", 42); // Begins playing 42 seconds into the media.
```